# Mutually Exclusive CheckBox for Windows Application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have been trying write a Mutually Exclusive CheckBox.

There are two checkBoxes in a Windows Form. If CheckBox1 is Checked then CheckBox2 should be UnChecked. I have been trying to achive this by handling the CheckedChanged event of the CheckBoxes, but has gone into an infinite loop.

My code snippets below.

```
Private Sub chkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBox1.CheckedChanged
    If chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBox2.CheckedChanged
    If chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    End If   
End Sub
```

Does someone have a Solution for this?

**EDIT**
I am not suppose to use RadioButtons here.

Comment: This is what a radio button list is for. Why confuse your users with non-standard UI?

Comment: @Jamiec, Some users will be able to Check only one CheckBox. Other CheckBox will be disabled for them based on their Role.

Comment: And so how does that stop you using a radio button list, you can still disable some radio's.

Comment: I'm with Jamiec, here. I'd go so far as to have a different set of controls for each user type. That way you've got RadioButtons for people who need RadioButtons and CheckBoxes for people who need CheckBoxes. Having a CheckBox with nonstandard behaviour will only confuse your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the checked-changing `if`s: each one of your handlers is firing itself, hence the infinite loop.
This should work:

```
Private Sub chkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBox1.CheckedChanged
    If chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked And chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked And chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub chkBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBox2.CheckedChanged
    If chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked And chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked And chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    End If   

End Sub
```

This avoids indirect recursion

Answer (score 2):

Use the same event handler for every checkbox button involved and protect from reentry with a static local variable

```
Private Sub chkBox_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkOnlyMyArea.CheckedChanged 
     Static inCheck as Boolean 
     if inCheck = true then 
         Exit Sub
     end if
     inCheck = true
     chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.UnChecked    
     chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.UnChecked    
     CheckBox c = CType(sender, CheckBox)
     c.CheckState = CheckState.Checked    
     inCheck = false
End Sub
```

Comment: Then a wild requirement appears forcing you to split things up, and here come the headaches

Comment: THe headaches are common in our profession. What happens in your answer if the checkboxes are three or four?....

Answer (score 1):

When I have more than two checkboxes and I need them to be mutually exclusive, yet I know I'll add some more later on, here is what I do:

```
 public class ObjectGroup
{
    public string ObjectName;
    public int GroupID;

    public ObjectGroup(int groupID, string objectName)
    {
        GroupID = groupID;
        ObjectName = objectName;
    }
}
```

In form definition:

```
private List<ObjectGroup> ObjectGroups;
```

In form Load:

```
//Set up checkbox groups
ObjectGroups = new List<ObjectGroup>();
ObjectGroups.Add(new ObjectGroup(1, "chStatic"));
ObjectGroups.Add(new ObjectGroup(1, "chNonStatic"));
```

And then in form body:

```
private void chNonStatic_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCheckboxState(sender as CheckBox);
}

private void chStatic_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCheckboxState(sender as CheckBox);
}
```

This function can reside in helper class or in form itself:

```
private void SetCheckboxState(CheckBox original)
    {
        var thisName = original.Name;
        var isChecked = original.Checked;
        //Find the object collection to which this control belongs
        var thisObject = (from q in ObjectGroups where q.ObjectName == thisName select q).FirstOrDefault();
        if (thisObject == null) return;
        var otherObjects = (from q in ObjectGroups where q.GroupID == thisObject.GroupID && q.ObjectName != thisName select q.ObjectName).ToList();
        foreach (var o in otherObjects)
        {
            CheckBox obj = this.Controls.Find(o, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                if (isChecked && obj.Checked) obj.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found  (works for more than 2 check-boxes)  is test the others for unchecked before you set checked.  This kills the infinite loop.  I know this is an old post but this method demonstrates 3 and more exclusive checked boxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        CheckBox2.Checked = False
        CheckBox3.Checked = False
    ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = False And CheckBox3.Checked = False Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
        CheckBox3.Checked = False
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False And CheckBox3.Checked = False Then
        CheckBox2.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
        CheckBox2.Checked = False
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False And CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        CheckBox3.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this checkchanged handler to all checkboxes in a groupbox.  Simple.

```
Private Sub ToggleCheckBoxOnEntry(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Static CurrentlySelectedbox As CheckBox

    If CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked Then
        CurrentlySelectedbox = sender
    End If

    For Each cntrl As CheckBox In grpVentMode.Controls
        If cntrl.Checked AndAlso cntrl.Name <> CurrentlySelectedbox.Name Then
            cntrl.Checked = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```